# SSL Connection on Solace MQTT Throwing Unknown Protocol error

Tags: ssl, solace

I am using Solace VMR for MQTT Publish/subscribe service . I am using paho library for publishing and subscribing . I need SSL connection with the Solace for the purpose. I configured Server and CA Certificate . Using SolAdmin , I can see that SSL service is enabled on port 8883 . So when I am trying to connect to Solace MQTT for publishing the data , it is throwing me a error :

**2016-09-09T16:54:50+0000  solace event: SYSTEM: SYSTEM_SSL_CONNECTION_REJECTED: - - SSL Connection rejected: reason (unknown protocol); connection to XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8883 from XXX.XX.XX.XXX:6217
6**.

I am using the URL as ssl://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8883. Please help where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is seen when a client uses TLS 1.0 to establish an SSL connection with the Solace VMR. TLS 1.0 is not supported on the Solace VMR as it is deemed to be unsecure.

The connection should be successful when using TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.